# chord of the graph of a function parallel to a given chord of the same graph

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the following exersice.Although intuitively it seems logical I cannot prove it formally.

Let $a,\,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\lt b$ and $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous and differentiable real function over $[a,b]$. 
Prove that $\exists c\exists d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\lt c\lt d\lt b$ and the straight lines that pass through the points $A(a,f(a)),\,B(b,f(b))$ and $C(c,f(c)),\,D(d,f(d))$ respectively are parallel to each other, thus $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}.$$

Can anyone give a hint or how to start? I am thinking that I have to define a suitable function and apply the MVT two times each one to an interval of the form $[a,ξ]$, $[ξ,b]$ where $ξ$ has been wisely selected?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Your suitable function is $$g(x)=f(x)-f(a)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$$

It's the IVT that you need, and the requirement on $\xi$ is just that $g(\xi)\neq 0$.

In the very special case where there is no such $\xi$, it's even easier, because then $f$ is $\ldots$

Comment: but this function is just to prove the MVT.I know that there is an interior point of [a,b],ξ such that the tangent of $C_f$ at Ξ(ξ,f(ξ)),$\varepsilon_Ξ$ is parallel to ΑΒ.
I just need to prove that there is a parallel line between AB and $\varepsilon_Ξ$ that intersects $C_f$  at two points at least!

Comment: Good! Now choose some value $y\in (g(a),g(\xi))$ and apply the IVT twice...

Comment: ohhh.....thank u so much......the only case that i need to clarify is that if g(a)=g(ξ)=g(b)-thus A,Ξ,B are collinear-then i work likewise on either [a,ξ] or [ξ,b].We find a $ξ'\in (a,ξ)$ from the MVT
Ιf $g(a)\neq g(ξ')$ then we find $t1\in (a,ξ')$,and $t2\in (ξ',ξ)$ as before....
if $g(a)=g(ξ')$ then A,Ξ,Ξ',Β collinear so we have the desired relation

Comment: @Perpendicular Yes, except in the process there is really no need for the MVT, $\xi$ (and $\xi'$) could be completely arbitrary.